# Yii create first test page

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am new to yii i have setup of sample yii demo application (default)n now i want to create new page but i am getting 404 error following are the steps i have followed.

1) In site Controller created new action

```
public function actionTest()
{
  $this->render('test');
}
```

2) created new page in view folder **test.php**

```
echo "test";
```

3) In **main.php** (config file) added following code

```
'urlManager' => array(

      'urlFormat' => 'path', 

      'showScriptName' => false,

      'caseSensitive' => false,

      'rules' => array(

      'test' => 'site/test',

      ),  
),
```

4) when i run the application with URL

```
http://localhost/YiiTest/test
```

then got the **error**

```
The requested URL /YiiTest/test was not found on this server.
```

Comment: I didn't tested, but aren't you missing the enablePrettyUrl set to true?

Comment: Do you put your file test.php on protected/views/site folder? And your URL,  localhost/folder/site/test?

Comment: Yes @AlejandroQuiroz i have put my test.php on protected/views/site folder ,but still it is not working

Comment: Type in your browser localhost/YiiTest/site/test and try to load it

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have rewrite your .htaccess file [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/)

Comment: Thanks for replay @Double H i have .htaccess with rewrite rule still it is not working 
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: And module rewrite is enabled or not.

Comment: yes it is working and showing the contents pf default yii webapp contents

Comment: Change 'test' => 'site/test',
By  array('test' => 'site/test',
),

Comment: HI tired above solution , now i got the different error 
The requested URL /Server/htdocs/FastBit/YiiTest/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: `/Server/htdocs/FastBit/YiiTest` if you are using xampp as server then your local url must be like localhost/FastBit/YiiTest   check your URL. may be its URL problem

Comment: No i am using wamp server and i have place code at different drive and created alias in wamp for that path